# How to subquery the same table

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to create new columns based on names in a specific column. When I filter the information, I get what I need, but there is a lot of null cells for information that did not meet the criteria of what I was asking for. Below is an example of my query and results.

I want to have the populated cells only show. So basically condense all the rows into 1 with all 6 fields populated.

Comment: Can we get a [MCVE] please?

Comment: What is the "ACTIVITY" column that you're grouping on? I suspect (without knowing more about your schema/data) that it should not be there in the group by clause.

Comment: Please post your code and data samples as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this simple.. Multiple SELECTs are not required and they will hamper the performance we are hitting the same table again and again.

```
SELECT logon_id,activity_date
,MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentOnSite_evt' THEN occurred END) First_Arrival
,MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentOnSite_evt' THEN occurred END) Last_Arrival
,MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'OrdActivityComplete_evt' THEN occurred END) First_Completion
,MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'OrdActivityComplete_evt' THEN occurred END) Last_Completion
,MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentEnRoute_evt' THEN occurred END) First_Enroute
,MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentEnRoute_evt' THEN occurred END) Last_Enroute
FROM activity
WHERE logon_id = 'e58684' AND Activity_Date = '20170127'
GROUP BY logon_id,activity_date
```

Comment: So my next question would be how can I only show the time for the results and not the date in each column?

Answer (score 1):

Try PIVOTing the rows. Like this

```
DECLARE @Activity TABLE
(
    LogonId INT,
    Activity_Date DATE,
    Activity VARCHAR(50),
    Occured DATE DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)

INSERT INTO @Activity
VALUES(1,GETDATE(),'ABC',GETDATE()),
(1,GETDATE(),'XYZ',GETDATE()-1),
(1,GETDATE(),'HIJ',GETDATE()-60)

SELECT
    *
    FROM @Activity
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Occured)
        FOR
        Activity IN
        (
            ABC,HIJ,XYZ
        )
    )Pvt
```

Input Rows

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
With a as (
Select min(occurred) min1, max(occured) max1
From activity
Where logon_id = 'aaa' and activity_date = '333' and activity in ('1'))
, B as (
Select min(occurred) min2, max(occured) max2
From activity
Where logon_id = 'aaa' and activity_date = '333' and activity in ('2')
)
, C as (
Select min(occurred) min3, max(occured) max3
From activity
Where logon_id = 'aaa' and activity_date = '333' and activity in ('3')
)
Select *
From a cross join b cross join c
```